# Missing getSelectedDataAsync method in Requirement Set Office.context.mailbox.item

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item we are currently having an issue that does not allow a smooth user experience at the moment due to the missing **getSelectedDataAsync method** in **Requirement Set Office.context.mailbox.item** for email Read mode (method is only available for Compose mode currently).

**In brief we would like to allow users to select a string from the body of a received email (read mode) and hand this over to the add-in as soon as the user opens the task pane via ribbon button.**
This was also requested by another developer via User Voice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/33235810-get-the-currently-selected-text-in-read-mode (41 votes so far).

First we are still hoping that this will be considered by Microsoft for the Roadmap because it is available already for email Compose mode and appointments and might only require little effort to also implement it for Read mode.

Secondly: Does anyone know of a good workaround to pass highlighted text from an email to the add-in? We've already tried with a Contextual add-in approach and RegEx but did not come to satisfying results here.

(I have been using this forum only once before. So hope you are not too strict if this might not be the right place for this question or I missed something in the description above...)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have any updates here. There are many factors that go into determining what new features/APIs are added, so I unfortunately cannot share any timelines or updates about this API.

Uservoice is the best way to get traction on this though.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks anyway and kind regards, Martin

Comment: @outlook-add-ins-team-msft Hello Add-ins team, can you please let us know when the support for getSelectedDataAsync in read mode will be added? It will be a great help to have this implemented.